# VIM: different font size in each split

Tags: vim

Is it possible to set different font sizes in different split views in vim? I often do :vsplit to open documentation in one and source in another view, and would like to use bigger font for reading documentation than for coding.
However, all of my attempts finished in changing font in all opened views.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vim is built on a classic terminal model: the entire screen must be completely monospaced.  There's no way to control the size of the text independently in different parts of the screen.  More's the pity.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose there is no difference when talking about gVIM?

Comment: Some actually consider that one of the finer points of Vim/gVim :)

Answer (score 5):

Type `:help 'guifont'`:

```
'guifont' 'gfn'     string  (default "")
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {only available when compiled with GUI enabled}
```

We can see that: `guifont` is a global option. So when you change it, it affect all windows.

In the future, this option can be `global or local to buffer/window`(such as `cm`).